# Dart exceptions not throwing Exception

Tags: dart, exception

following code as docs mention:

```
try {
   breedMoreLlamas1();
} on OutOfLlamasException {
  // A specific exception
  buyMoreLlamas();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  // Anything else that is an exception
  print('Unknown exception: $e');
} catch (e) {
  // No specified type, handles all
  print('Something really unknown: $e');
}

void breedMoreLlamas1() {
  print('buyMoreLlamas_1');
  throw Exception;
}
```

I get buyMoreLlamas_1 and the message Something really unknown: Exception
Shouldn't be : Unknown exception: Exception

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where are these docs that you mention? This is clearly not a [mre]. Edit your question to have the minimal reproducible code.

Comment: You are throwing the `Exception` `Type` object, not an *instance* of an `Exception`.  You should be using `throw Exception();` (or better: `throw Exception('Your error message');`).

Comment: Or even better, a concrete subclass of `Exception`. You should never throw instances of the class `Exception` in production code, it doesn't provide information to the catcher about what went wrong, or how they can recover. Exceptions are intended to be caught and recovered from, not crash the program.